# Popuating form fields from MySQL using AJAX and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, auto-populate

I followed a tutorial to adapt the code. Here I am trying trying to auto-populate my form fields with AJAX when an 'ID' value is provided. I am new to Jquery and can't get to work this code.

**Edit 1 : While testing the code, Jquery isn't preventing the form to submit and sending the AJAX request.**

HTML form

```
<form id="form-ajax" action="form-ajax.php">
    <label>ID:</label><input type="text" name="ID" /><br />
    <label>Name:</label><input type="text" name="Name" /><br />
    <label>Address:</label><input type="text" name="Address" /><br />
    <label>Phone:</label><input type="text" name="Phone" /><br />
    <label>Email:</label><input type="email" name="Email" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="fill from db" />
</form>
```

I tried changing Jquery code but still I couldn't get it to work. I think Jquery is creating a problem here. But I am unable to find the error or buggy code. Please it would be be very helpful if you put me in right direction.

**Edit 2 : I tried using**

```
return false;
```

instead of

```
event.preventDefault();
```

**to prevent the form from submitting but still it isn't working. Any idea what I am doing wrong here ?**

Jquery

```
jQuery(function($) {

// hook the submit action on the form
$("#form-ajax").submit(function(event) {
    // stop the form submitting
    event.preventDefault();

    // grab the ID and send AJAX request if not (empty / only whitespace)
    var IDval = this.elements.ID.value;
    if (/\S/.test(IDval)) {

        // using the ajax() method directly
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : ajax.php,
            cache : false,
            dataType : "json",
            data : { ID : IDval },
            success : process_response,
            error: function(xhr) { alert("AJAX request failed: " + xhr.status); }
        });


    }
    else {
        alert("No ID supplied");
    }
};


function process_response(response) {
    var frm = $("#form-ajax");
    var i;

    console.dir(response);      // for debug

    for (i in response) {
        frm.find('[name="' + i + '"]').val(response[i]);
    }
}

});
```

Ajax.php

```
if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
if ($_GET['action'] == 'fetch') {
    // tell the browser what's coming
    header('Content-type: application/json');

    // open database connection
    $db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host:localhost;', 'xyz', 'xyz');

    // use prepared statements!
    $query = $db->prepare('select * from form_ajax where ID = ?');
    $query->execute(array($_GET['ID']));
    $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    // send the data encoded as JSON
    echo json_encode($row);
    exit;
 }
}
```

Comment: `frm.find('[name="' + i + '"]')` returns an array. That's why `.val()` cannot place value in your input field.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot understand how this returns an array. Please elaborate.

Comment: I couldn't find from where does this `data` in `data : data,` come?

Comment: @code-jaff I have corrected it.

Comment: @DeveloperVidit OK, it's an array-like Object... Try sth like: 
`var name = frm.find('[name="' + i + '"]'); $(name[0]).val( 'text' );`.... read [HERE](http://api.jquery.com/find/) for more.

Comment: okay, then there is no place you are setting a value for key `action` which is used in php within an if condition `$_GET['action']`. Moreover, still you didn't tell us what is the actual issue, precisely.

Comment: First of all please answer why my jquery code isn't preventing the form from submitting ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you're parsing your json response into a javascript object (hash). This [jQuery method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) should help. It also looks like you're not posting your form using jquery, but rather trying to make a get request. To properly submit the form using jquery, use something like this:

```
$.post( "form-ajax.php", $( "#form-ajax" ).serialize() );
```

Also, have you tried adding id attributes to your form elements?

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>
```

It would be easier to later reach them with

```
var element = $('#'+element_id);
```

If this is not a solution, can you post the json that is coming back from your request?

Comment: Is it necessary to parse json response into javascript object ? I have directly used echo json_encode and using the response from console.

JSON that should come back is : {"ID":"123","Name":"Test Only","Address":"123 Smith Street Jonestown 2000 NSW","Phone":"0123456789","Email":"test@example.com"}

Comment: If you've been able to access it as a javascript object (I dont know what exact error you were having) then maybe using element ids should work well for you. Just set the id attributes to be like the name attributes and my suggestion should work

Comment: But jQuery isn't preventing the form to submit and sending the AJAX request. On submitting the form it is redirected to 'form-ajax.php'. Any idea where I am wrong ?

Comment: Looks like you're not posting the form using jquery. I edited the answer to include how to post a form with ajax + jquery.

Comment: I don't want to post the form, I want to prevent it from posting and make an AJAX request to bring the data and auto populate it in the form.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the submit input with button:

```
<button type="button" id="submit">
```

**Note the type="button"**.
It's mandatory to prevent form submition

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").on("click", function(e) {
          $.ajax({type:"get",
                  url: "ajax.php",
                  data: $("#form-ajax").serialize(),
                  dataType: "json",
                  success: process_response,
                  error: function(xhr) { alert("AJAX request failed: " + xhr.status); }
           });
    });
});
```